# How to make an adjustable navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

First, sorry for my English. I'm trying to make a page for a college project of mine. I've learned a couple of stuff reading books and watching some videos, but I couldn't find the answer for this. I'm not a professional programmer nor a designer, but this is an interesting challenge as a Linux sysadmin.

I know how to make a fixed navbar, but the point is I need a adaptable / adjustable navbar after the user does a scroll. For some design guidelines, I need to keep (1) a row filled with dropdown menus, (2) a somewhat big logo and (3) another row with the internal links of the page (home, about us, and stuff like that). After scrolling, the (2) and (3) must merge in the classical fixed navbar. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOzaK.png)

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some code showing what you have tried, then we can make some suggestions on how to improve it

Comment: [This guide](http://lukedowding.com/change-nav-bar-menu-add-css-class-scroll/) should help a lot :)